# MVC 3- Grid. Export Data into Excel and PDF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3 Web Grid. I need to export the data into excel 2003 and Higher and to PDF.

I have two button under the grid, When I click on the first button, I should be able to export  to excel 2003 and save the data.

When I click on the second button, I should be able to export in to PDF format.

Using Grid View in Webforms, I have done that, but using MVC3, I have not done that.

Any directions please? Is there anything that comes up with in MVC3 framework for export functionality.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there anything that comes up with in MVC3 framework for export functionality.

No nothing. To export to Excel you could use CSV and use a controller action which will fetch the data from wherever you fetched it initially to display on the grid and return a File content with CSV:

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
{
    byte[] csvData = ... fetch the data from your repository and convert to CSV
    return File(csvData, "text/csv", "data.csv");
}
```

To export to PDF, well, nothing built-in .NET. You will need a third party library. Personally I use [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) to achieve this functionality.

Comment: CSV is by far the easiest way for excel. If you need formatting you need to look into excel Interoperability. For PDFs another good library is [PDFSharp and Migradoc](http://www.pdfsharp.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You can check [here](http://adambielecki.blogspot.ca/2013/05/exporting-data-to-excel-and-csv-in.html) for an easy way to export to CSV. You don't have to worry about converting your data to CSV, this will do it.